# Subscribe to events in VBA?

Tags: events, vba, subscribe

Did I understood correctly that you can't subscribe to an event other than using the VBA Editor's control name + event name comboboxes? There is no combobox.change+=eventhandler syntax available as in other languages like C#, is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Event handling is done via naming convention in VB6/VBA.
The name can be the name of the control itlsef, or it can be a variable declared `WithEvents`. By assigning this variable a different reference, you start receiving events from that new object. This can be seen as dynamical subscribing.

However, certain environments can provide additional means. For example, in Excel some placeable objects have hidden properties, such as `Button.OnAction`. You can assign a name of a macro to this property (as a string), and it will be called on button press.