# Creating a new IUI Automation Handler object in order to subscribe to an automation event

Tags: vba, ms-access, automation, ui-automation

So, here it goes. To start, A disclaimer, I understand that MS Access is not built for this kind of work. It is my only option at this time.

I have done just a bit of Automation using UIAutomationClient and I have successfully used its other features, however I cannot for the life of me get it to subscribe to events.

Normally, it is supposed to be a bit like this:

```
Dim CUI as new CUIAutomation
 Dim FocusHandler as IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler
    Set  FocusHandler = new IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(onFocusChanged)
     C.AddFocusChangedEventHandler(Element,TreeScope_Children, null, FocusHandler)
 end function
 '
 '
 Function onFocusChanged(src as Object, args as AutomationEventArgs)
     ''my code here
 end function
```

Yet when I attempt this, I get the error "expected end of statement" on the line:
`FocusHandler = new IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(onFocusChanged)`

additionally, if I leave off the (onFocusChanged) I get the error "Invalid use of new Keyword".

It seems like I am missing a reference somewhere. The usual drop down when using "new" does not contain the IUI handler classes though they are in the object library.

I am not sure if there is just some piece I am not accounting for in the code since I am using vba, but all examples seem to be for .net or C#/C++. Any help would be appreciated.

Additionally, I have no problem finding the element in question and all other pieces work fine. If you need any other pieces of the code let me know.

Edit: added set to line 3. No change in the problem though.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216031/subscribe-to-events-in-vba

Comment: It's `Set FocusHandler = new IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler`. But I'm not that experienced in UI automation and I see a bunch of things that likely won't work. C++ examples generally should be translateable to VBA, though.

Comment: I appreciate the responses. I did already try adding "set" but it still causes invalid use of new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

After two years this probably isn't relevant any more, but perhaps somebody else encounters this problem... The answer is to create a new class that implements the HandleAutomationEvent method.

Here I created a class named clsInvokeEventHandler and (importantly) set the Instancing property to PublicNotCreatable:

```
Option Explicit
Implements IUIAutomationEventHandler
Private Sub IUIAutomationEventHandler_HandleAutomationEvent(ByVal sender As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement, ByVal eventId As Long)
    Debug.Print sender.CurrentName
End Sub
```

And to use it:

```
Sub StartInvokeHandler()
    Dim oUIA As New CUIAutomation8
    Dim oRoot As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim InvokeHandler As clsInvokeEventHandler
    Set InvokeHandler = New clsInvokeEventHandler
    Set oRoot = oUIA.GetRootElement
    oUIA.AddAutomationEventHandler UIA_Invoke_InvokedEventId, oRoot, TreeScope_Descendants, Nothing, InvokeHandler
End Sub
```